# Is it compulsory in Islam to get married?

Tags: nikah

Is it compulsory in Islam to get married?

I'm 32 years of age, and for some reason, I did not get married somehow.  Parents negligence were the main reason of delaying, but now they are looking for an alliance for me, and now I'm under pressure because I do not want to marry person who my family has chosen. I'm mature enough to choose a life partner for myself, as if I feel, if I marry I will defiantly do get that. But now I'm facing a lot of stress from my family. They are not listening to me. They just want me to get married at any cost, and the alliance they want for me ask dowry in lacs, or they bring alliance who is double of my age.  I'm very religious and I'm fed up of all this torture.  I want to escape or to die.  Please help me getting answer for my problem.  I don't want to get married.  I don't even want to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Waalaykumsalam, getting married is sunnah (is what the Prophet Muhammad PBUH do) and marrying the one you like is also sunnah as in Quran said, translation:

*And of His signs is that He created for you from yourselves mates that you may find tranquillity in them; and He placed between you affection and mercy. Indeed in that are signs for a people who give thought.* 
[Ar-Rum:21]

Married someone that may bring *tranquillity* to you and your family.

Haven't found someone yet? Keep looking and focus on improving yourself because of Allah.

Take care of your ibadah, good deeds and akhlak. InsyaAllah you will find one and Allah will show you the way.

Keep the faith flying high. My prayer goes to you, always.

:)